# emmet features in VSC not working after editing settings

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm new to VSC environment and I used a flutter dev environment for the first time. Coming from a raw basic text++ editor I fell in love with all the fancy features that came with it, such as closing tags and the auto building tags.

for example,

I could type something like

```
.test|c
```

and it would expand out to

```
<div class="test">

</div><!--test-->
```

which was incredibly useful. I've been a web dev for a long time and I've built out fairly large full-stack reactJS applications but never used any aid, and I see the absolute value in it.

In attempting to mimic these settings in visual studio (mac os), I did the following:

code -> preferences -> settings.

Under workplace settings I created this snippet from emmet documentation:

```
"emmet.preferences":{
    "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->",
  },
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html" : {
        "filters" :"bem"
    }
},
```

but alas, no effect. I noticed emmet doesn't notice the `.test|c` as it doesn't auto-generate.

Any suggestions what going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your settings.json

```
  "emmet.preferences":{
    "filter.commentAfter": "\n<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->",
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  // Enable XHTML dialect for HTML syntax
  // “html”: “xhtml”
    "html" : {
      "filters" :"html, c"
      }
  },
```

Learned this from [Caffeine Creations](https://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/closing-comments-in-emmet-with-visual-studio-code/)

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

```
"emmet.preferences":{
   "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->",
},
```

as you had it is correct.

---

Now, as for the `syntaxProfiles` entry it depends on how you plan to use the `comment filter`.

To use as `.wrapper|c`   (explicitly using the `|c`):

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html" : {
      "filters" :"html"  // put any other filters here as `"html, bem"`
     }
},
```

To use as `.wrapper`   (implicitly using the `|c`):

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html" : {
      "filters" :"html c"  // put any other filters here as `"html, bem, c"`
     }
},
```

With this last version, a comment will be added to  **all** tags, probably not what you want.  See [emmet: implicit filter calls](https://docs.emmet.io/filters/#implicit-filter-call).

---

If you want `div`s to be separated by newlines as in your example, do this:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
   "format.forceIndentationForTags": ["script", "div"],
   "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
 },
```

now `div` (and `script`) tags will appear as:

```
<div class="test">
  |
</div><!--test-->
```

---

Finally, it appears you aren't seeing emmet functionality at all.  See [enabling emmet in other file types](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types):

> ```
> "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>     "javascript": "javascriptreact",
>     "vue-html": "html",
>     "razor": "html",
>     "plaintext": "jade"
> }
> ```

I am not sure which filetype you are using but you may need to map it to `javascriptreact` or `html` for example as in the above sample code.